# How to make a fixed banner on horizontal tab scrolling?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this layout wherein the user may scroll vertically and horinzontally. It has tabs and banners as well.

> If the user scrolls vertically, the banner collapses. But if the user
>   scroll horizontally between tabs, I want the banner on a fixed
>   position or is steady.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/campaign_banner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `app:layout_scrollFlags="pin"` also when user switches tab call programmatically following code

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
```